# Delete an item/element from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I want to be able to delete an item/element form localStorage. I can delete it before reloading. The `removeButton` removes the selected item form LocalStorage when clicked, it works just fine but once the page reloads, the button does not longer respond on the items saved in localStorage. Is there any way to make it work after reloading?

```
let ids1 = document.getElementById('ids')
let ids2 = document.getElementById('ids2')

let buttonCreateTask = document.getElementsByClassName('create')
let newd = document.getElementsByClassName('newd')

let prevContent = localStorage.getItem('saved');
if (prevContent) { newd[0].innerHTML = prevContent}

function createTask (){ 

let paro = document.createElement('p')
paro.innerText = ids1.value + '\n' + ids2.value

let removeButton = document.createElement('button')
removeButton.innerHTML = 'REMOVE' 

paro.appendChild(removeButton)

removeButton.onclick = function() {
    paro.remove()
    localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML)
   
}

if(ids1.value !== ''){ 
    if(ids2.value !== ''){ 
        
        newd[0].appendChild(paro)
ids1.value = ''
ids2.value = ''

localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML) 

    }else {
       alert('missing description')
    }
}else {
     alert('missing value')
}

buttonCreateTask[0].addEventListener('click', createTask )
```

I have tried adding an if statement on `removeButton` since the items are store in `prevContent` in order to display if they are not deleted when the page reloads but it does not remove it

```
remove.onclick = function() {
    if(paro){ 
    paro.remove()
    localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML)
    if(prevContent !== ''){
       delete prevContent      
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. If that doesn't work, I'd try commenting out the code that doesn't have to do with local storage to see if you can pinpoint the problem. Right now there is a lot going on and maybe an error is getting thrown in another part of your code that is causing a problem down stream.

```
removeButton.onclick = function() {
    paro.remove()
    localStorage.removeItem('saved')
   
}
```

Comment: right but since is a todo app there is more than one item generated and if i only do ```localStorage.removeItem('saved')``` instead of ```localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML)``` not only the item selected will be removed but all ```'saved'``` and its content including unselected items